# Manage console.log() as data input

Tags: javascript, typescript

For my curiosity, i demanded myself why in this fragment of code when call a function, it return my object that i declared with declaration Undefined?
here follow my example :

```
var scarpaAcquistata = {
    marca: "nike",
    numero: 42,
    colore: "rosso"
};

function stampaListascarpe(prodotto) {
     stampa= console.log(prodotto.colore, prodotto.marca, prodotto.numero);
    return stampa;
}
console.log(stampaListascarpe(scarpaAcquistata));
```

the function return : `nike,42,rosso,undefined` how come happen it?
so how could be possible to manage data output console as a input data without take this error "Undefined"?

Comment: you're using `console.log` twice, once inside `stampaListascarpe` (which returns undefined) and once outside it, including it's return value.

Comment: i'm doing some experiment for study...

Comment: Maybe I can help you by redirecting you to [usage of console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Outputting_text_to_the_console) documentation, since what this problem is revolving around it.

Answer (score 3):

Inside the function, you're already calling `console.log` which, besides actually printing what you passed to it (that is, the fields in the `prodotto` instance), also returns `undefined`.

Then you return that `undefined` and `console.log` it outside the function, which prints the last `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

`console.log()` does not return a variable, yet you are assigning `stampa` to its output. Since there is no output, `stampa` will remain undefined.

If you want `stampaListascarpe()` to simply return the `prodotto` scoped variable, you can do so trivially:

```
var scarpaAcquistata = {
    marca: "nike",
    numero: 42,
    colore: "rosso"
};

function stampaListascarpe(prodotto) {
    return prodotto;
}
console.log(stampaListascarpe(scarpaAcquistata));
```

Comment: I can't see what you edited in my answer. Can you please tell me?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca My apologies, I accidentally edited your answer instead of mine. I reverted the changes. The change was adding the code.

Comment: i thought that output could be see like a input data...ok now it's clear